# How to duplicate backslash character in a String?

Tags: java, string, duplicates, char

I am trying to duplicate backslash characters inside a string.
The string is a directory path!
I wrote a function, but it doesn't return a correct result!

When I tested the function with

```
C:\Users\Asus i7\Desktop\untitled1ghthr\src\sample\panda.mp3
```

it returns

```
C:\\User\s\Asus \i7\Desk\top\untitled1g\hth\r\src\\sample\panda.mp3
```

While i want it to return

```
C:\\Users\\Asus i7\\Desktop\\untitled1ghthr\\src\\sample\\panda.mp3
```

Code of the function

```
public StringBuffer add(String ch) {
    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer(ch);
    for(int i=0;i<ch.length();i++){
        if (ch.charAt(i)=='\\'){
            str.insert(i, '\\');
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: If you insert stuff, your indexes change.

Comment: `string.replace("\\", "\\\\")` but it is better to use Paths as mentioned in one of the answers

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Paths.get : [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...))

The method you are trying to use will not work on all OS.